# A subset of a metric space $X$ is nowhere dense iff the complement of it's closure is (everywhere) dense?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A\subset X$  is nowhere dense, then $int({\overline A)} = \phi$.

$\implies$ No neighbourhood of $x \in A$ is in ${\overline A}$.

$\implies $ Every neighbourhood of $x$ is in $({\overline A})^c.$

$\implies x$ is a limit point of $({\overline A})^c$.

I'm stuck now on how to show the closure of $({\overline A})^c$ is $X$, and the converse part also.

Comment: No neighborhood of $x \in A$ is in $\overline A$ $\not \implies$ every neighbohood of x is in $(\overline A)^c$.  In fact $x \in A \subset \overline A$ so $x \not \in (\overline A)^c$ so no neighborhood of x is in $(\overline A)^c$.

Comment: $(\overline A)^c$ *isn't X.  and can't be shown to be X.  $\overline{(\overline A)^c}$ is X and can be shown by showing every point of X is a limit point of $(\overline A)^c$.

Answer (score 2):

$int \overline A = \emptyset$

No neighborhood of $x \in \overline A$ is entirely in $ \overline A$.

$\implies$ every neighborhood of $x \in \overline A$ contains a point of $\overline A^c$.

So every point of $\overline A$ is a limit point of $\overline A^c$.

Every point of X is in either in $\overline A^c$ or $\overline A$ so every point of X is either in $\overline A^c$ or is a limit point of $\overline A^c$.

So $\overline A^c$ is dense in X.

===

if $x \in int \overline A$ (i.e. if $int \overline A$ is not empty). Then there exists a neighborhood of $x$ that is entirely in $\overline A$.  Thus x is not an limit point of $\overline A ^c$.  And $x \in \overline A$ so x $x \not \in \overline A ^c$.  So the existence of $x$ shows not every point of $X$ is a limit point or a point of $\overline A ^c$.

So $\overline A ^c$ is not dense in X.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is that the interior of $\bar{A}$ is empty and you want to prove that $X\setminus\bar{A}$ is dense.

Let $x\in X$ and consider an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ (an open ball, if you prefer).

We need to show that $U\cap(X\setminus\bar{A})\ne\emptyset$. But, if $U\cap(X\setminus\bar{A})=\emptyset$, we have that
$$
U\subseteq \bar{A}
$$
and therefore $x$ belongs to the interior of $\bar{A}$.

Conversely, assume $U\cap(X\setminus\bar{A})$ is dense in $X$. Suppose $x$ belongs to the interior of $\bar{A}$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\subseteq \bar{A}$. This implies $U\cap(X\setminus\bar{A})=\emptyset$, contradicting the hypothesis that $U\cap(X\setminus\bar{A})$ is dense in $X$.